# google appscript to move folder content to another folder

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I am new at this and not programmer or a coder.

I am trying to make google app script to move folder content to another folder in google drive

I came across this [link](https://www.labnol.org/code/19975-move-file-between-folders)

I am using below code and it runs without error, but the files are not moved.

```html
function myFunction() {
var source_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1fMCHA4-b2a2BQjO0VD2dd5m4V5WvXz9D')

var dest_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1LbZchJflfcnOKqSPYCdGcFTI_7AAVJIi')

function moveFiles(source_folder, dest_folder){

  var files = source_folder.getFiles();

  while (files.hasNext()) {

    var file = files.next();
    dest_folder.addFile(file);
    source_folder.removeFile(file);

  }
}
}
```

Can someone advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Try:

```
function myFunction() {

  const source_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1fMCHA4-b2a2BQjO0VD2dd5m4V5WvXz9D')
  const dest_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1LbZchJflfcnOKqSPYCdGcFTI_7AAVJIi')

  // Call the function:
  moveFiles(source_folder, dest_folder)

  function moveFiles(source_folder, dest_folder) {

    const files = source_folder.getFiles()

    while (files.hasNext()) {

      const file = files.next()
      file.moveTo(dest_folder)

    }

  }

}
```

Rather than copy and delete each file, just move it!

The main problem you had was that you were not `calling` your function. You had only defined it.

**Learn More:**

- [File.moveTo()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#movetodestination)

Comment: Hi NEWAZA, thank you so much, I run the above code and it ran perfectly.

Comment: Sure will do that, right now.

Answer (score 0):

#### Similar to the first answer but uses the Drive API to perform the move

```
function movefiles() {
  const sfldr = DriveApp.getFolderById('sid');
  const dfldr = DriveApp.getFolderById('did');
  const files = sfldr.getFiles()
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    const file = files.next()
    Drive.Files.update({ "parents": [{ "id": dfldr.getId() }] }, file.getId(), null, { supportsAllDrives: true });
  }
}
```

[Drive.Files.update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update)

Comment: Hi Cooper, thank you so much, I tried you code as well and it work even better. appreciated and many thanks.

Comment: I thought it might. API's tend to be a little faster