# Parents not update when i use drive api update

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

Im trying to use drive api to move a sheet i created with sheets API to another folder but the parents not update and stay in the root folder, anyone can help me whats wrong? im using apps script btw.

```
function moveFile(fileId){
  try {
    const new_folder = '10MrKRl73LY-upJ0Wd2YBxXgba97fhhoe';
    const file = Drive.Files.get(fileId);
    const previousParent = file.parents[0].id;
    console.log(previousParent);
    const files = Drive.Files.update({
      removeParents: previousParent,
      addParents: new_folder,
      fields: 'id, parents',

    }, fileId);
    console.log(files);
    return files.status;
  } catch (err) {
    // TODO (developer) - Handle exception
    console.log('Failed with error %s', err.message);
  }
}
```

im using v2, idk why app script dont let me use the v3 of drive API[image]

Comment: Try this: - [Drive.Files.update](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72467900/7215091)

Comment: Thanks man!, its crazy how there is nothing about this in documentation :S